# Why return the Windows BOOL data type and not int?

Tags: c++, windows

From 
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
BOOL WINAPI GetMessage(
  _Out_    LPMSG lpMsg,
  _In_opt_ HWND  hWnd,
  _In_     UINT  wMsgFilterMin,
  _In_     UINT  wMsgFilterMax
);
```

It states the following :

"If the function retrieves a message other than `WM_QUIT`, the return value is nonzero.
If the function retrieves the `WM_QUIT` message, the return value is zero. 
If there is an error, the return value is **-1**."

---

Aren't `boolean` values either `true` or `false`?. It appears we have three options here, `true`, `false`, and `oopsie_daisy`....

So, while typing this I thought I should go check `WinDef.h` and in it I found :

---

`typedef int BOOL;`

---

Hrmmm...

`BOOL` is just an `int`.

So exactly WHAT is the purpose of that? Is it just another anachronism like we find the Windows API littered with?

Why doesn't `GetMessage()` return an `int` value?

I know that ultimately it doesn't make a difference, I am simply curious whether anybody has an answer as it has been bugging me as of late.

Thank you.

PS:

In regards to my `oopsie_daisy` remark, I realise that it can be any integer value, I was speaking in the context of the function having 3 options, not that BOOL only has 3 possible values.

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_

Comment: Hint: Windows API was invented between 1981-1990. `bool` was added to  C in 1999. (Oddly, C++ has had `bool` since 1989)

Comment: This is not unusual for object oriented code: `True`, `false` are the output of a good running well defined process, error is the rest which fell through. For example in Java for the object Boolean be `null`, 0 or 1.

Comment: Simply because in the early days of winapi, bool didn't exist

Comment: Obligatory question: who cares? `BOOL` is known to be a `typedef` for `int`. APIs returning a `BOOL` document the meaning of possible return values, with most only distinguishing between `0` and `non-0`. So, no big problem there, other than aesthetics maybe. *\[EDIT\]* That said, I don't understand the downvotes. It sounds like a perfectly legitimate `winapi` question to me.

Comment: Not only does the Windows API predate any kind of boolean type in standard C, it also predates any kind of exception handing in the Windows API. So the simplest way to return "error" is to return something which isn't `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: @MooingDuck Nice, that's excellent and very relevant.

Comment: @dxiv Yeah "who cares?" is a good question. And like I said, ultimately, it doesn't make a difference, I was simply curious and thought there'd be people here who could answer that's all.

Comment: Just curious why I'm getting downvoted?

Comment: I think down votes are due to the question only being answerable by who ever decided to use `BOOL` over `int`. An attempt by anyone else is just speculation.

Comment: @nate I guess I should have worded it differently. Perhaps Why WOULD one use `BOOL` instead of `int`? I was just using `GetMessage()` as an example, I realise only the person who implemented that could give the real answer. I was more curious as to why, generally speaking, a `BOOL` would be used when more than 2 results can be returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [When will GetMessage return -1?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873) on The Old New Thing:

> Originally, the Get­Message function did not have a failure mode. If you passed invalid parameters, then you invoked undefined behavior, and you probably crashed.

So, originally, GetMessage returned either TRUE or FALSE.  The choice of `BOOL` was therefore perfectly reasonable at the time.

As for why the signature didn't change when the behaviour changed, that's presumably just inertia and/or backwards compatibility.

Comment: Backwards compatibility is the reason for a lot of quirks in the windows api

Comment: Well, atleast I am not the only person who found it bizarre.

Comment: Backwards compatibility is why WORD is 16-bits on machines with 32-bit words, and 16-bits on machines with 64-bit words.

Answer (score 1):

`BOOL` indicates that in the normal case, no parameter errors, the value can be interpreted as a boolean value, per the usual C convention of 0 = *false*, as it ¹originally was for `GetMessage`:

*ECMA-234 §8.3:*

> **”** The return value of the GetMessage() function is TRUE if a message other than WM_QUIT is retrieved. The return value is FALSE if a WM_QUIT message is retrieved.

Why this wasn't changed when `GetMessage` was changed to also return an error indicator, is probably not possible to answer.

<sup>*Notes:*

¹ http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-234.htm</sup>